# What devices is supported by getusermedia

Tags: javascript, webcam, getusermedia

I am using `getusermedia()` to use webcams for an online application. I am using a Logitech C615 webcam (plug and play) and it works great.

Will `getusermedia()` only work with plug and play webcams or will it also work with webcams with drivers.

In my opinion webcams with drivers will have DLL files andyou will need to include DLL files in the code to work, so any webcam with driver will not be detected by `getusermedia()`.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getUserMedia works through your local web browser. The browser code enumerates the video devices on your machine using the operating system's device enumeration API.

Webcams that work with browsers, when their drivers are installed correctly, show up in that enumeration.

If the cam's driver requires the software using it to bind to a particular custom DLL, then it doesn't work with web browsers. But then it's not much of a webcam, eh?

You may have a special purpose camera device, for machine vision or some such thing. But it it doesn't have standalone driver, browsers cant't use it.